# How to find tty of USB modem on raspberry pi?

Tags: raspberry-pi, usb, modem

I want send AT commands to USB modem connected to raspberry pi. I have found some helps mentioning that USB modem is usually connected as ttyACM or ttyUSB device, but I have no ttyACM or ttyUSB device. I have devices from tty1 to tty63, but I do not know how to identify which one is used by the modem.

I have tried to find the device by storing devices list with the modem unconnected and then compare device list after the modem is pluged in:

```
ls /dev/ > dev_list_1.txt
(plug the modem in)
ls /dev/ | diff --suppress-common-lines -y - dev_list_.txt
```

returns to me:

```
bsg                               <
sda                               <
sg0
```

I have tried to connect the modem with cu tool:

```
sudo cu -l sda
sudo cu -l sg0
```

but both returns:

```
cu: open (/dev/sg0): Permission denied
cu: sg0: Line in use
```

So I tried also use minicom and configure serial communication to /dev/sg0 or /dev/sda but it does not work either.

So I think I need to find right tty device used by the modem to be able to communicate with it. But how to find it?

Comment: Using the command `lsusb -vvv` will show you much information relating to USB devices connected to the machine you are running. Additionally, you may `physical USB device hierarchy as a tree. Verbosity can be increased twice with v option...` as the manual page says.

Comment: Thanks, it says many informations, unfortunately it does not say anything abut /dev/tty. I have tried lsusb -t already and it gives me info, that the modem is running on port 4, Dev 6. I also know idVendor and idproduct of the modem. but I do not know if it can be used for serial communication with the modem as every manual on net says "write to /dev/ttyACM0"

Comment: You have used `sudo raspi-config` and enabled the interface?

Comment: Have you tried `ls -l /dev/serial/by-id` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can look for `/sys/class/tty/*/device` entries and ignore all the links that points to serial8250 since those are not USB devices.

With shell script:

```
for device in /sys/class/tty/*/device
do
    case $(readlink $device) in
        *serial8250)    # e.g. ../../../serial8250
            ;;
        *)              # e.g. ../../../1-3:3.1
            echo $device | rev | cut -d/ -f2 | rev
            ;;
    esac;
done | sed 's@^@/dev/@'
```

which produces

```
/dev/ttyACM0
/dev/ttyACM1
/dev/ttyS0
```

with my phone connected. You might get more than the usb devices (e.g. ttyS0) but at least this should give you all the usb serial devices the kernel know about (and if the device does not populate /sys/class/tty/ it almost certainly is not a serial device).

This is based on the `list_ports` function logic in the [libserialport library](https://sigrok.org/gitweb/?p=libserialport.git;a=blob;f=linux.c;h=8f320859dc91b329caf6688a3e250ad371b6a5d5;hb=HEAD#l190).

Answer (score 0):

I'm using picocom >=3.0 to identify which tty accepts AT commands for USB modems (tested on Sierra EM7455).

My script looks like

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

for tty in $(ls /dev/ttyUSB*); do
    echo "Checking $tty"
    picocom -qrX -b 9600 $tty
    sleep 1
    result=$(echo "AT&F" | picocom -qrix 1000 $tty)
    if [ "$result" = "AT&F" ]; then
        echo "Found AT compatible modem at $tty"
    else
        echo "No AT compatible modem at $tty"
    fi
done
```

Of course you can adapt this by replacing `/dev/ttyUSB*` with whatever fits your modem.